# SQL Server : Msg 102, Level 15, State 1,Incorrect syntax near '('

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my first time to write SQL and I try to find out the wrong but I can't find out which place is wrong.

My version of SQL Server is SQL Server Management Studio 17

```
CREATE TABLE nohours AS
(SELECT Dnumber, SUM(Hours) FROM DEPARTMENT,PROJECT,WORKS_ON
WHERE Pno=Pnumber AND Dnum=Dnumber
GROUP BY Dnumber
);
```

and I got an error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1
>   Incorrect syntax near '('

Comment: You have MySQL as the tag but reference SQL Server in the question. They aren't the same product and use different SQL syntax. If you are using SQL Server, I think you are looking for the SELECT INTO command - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-into-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Dnumber, SUM(Hours) as Hours
INTO nohours 
FROM DEPARTMENT,PROJECT,WORKS_ON
WHERE Pno=Pnumber AND Dnum=Dnumber
GROUP BY Dnumber
```

This will create the `nohours` table from the results of the `SELECT`. The MS documentation on the command is here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-into-clause-transact-sql

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE nohours 
(
Dnumber INT,
TotalHours BIGINT
)
GO
INSERT INTO nohours 
(
Dnumber ,
TotalHours 
)

SELECT Dnumber, SUM(Hours) AS TotalHours 
FROM DEPARTMENT,PROJECT,WORKS_ON
WHERE Pno=Pnumber AND Dnum=Dnumber
GROUP BY Dnumber
```